# Symfony 6 - Class declared in services.yaml not found

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with registering a class as a service in `services.yaml`.

I have created a class `MenuBuilder.php` in Symfony 6 that looks somewhat like this.

### src/Menu/MenuBuilder.php

```php
namespace App\Menu;

class MenuBuilder
{

    public function createMainMenu(array $options)
    {
       // method logic
    }

}
```

Now, when I want to register it as a service: *(and use it in twig with KnpMenuBundle)*

### config/services.yaml

```
parameters:

services:

  _defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

  App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
      - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
      - '../src/Entity/'
      - '../src/Kernel.php'

  app.menu_builder:
    class: App\Menu\MenuBuilder
    arguments: [ "@knp_menu.factory" ]
    tags:
      - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createMainMenu, alias: main }
```

I get an error `Class "App\Menu\MenuBuilder" not found.`

I tried making some other classes (ex. `Test/TestClass`) and namespaces and it doesn't work with freshly created classes.

On the other hand it i fiddled around with the naming and it recognized my entities and factories.

1. I tried clearing the cache
2. I am in development mode
3. I am getting this message when calling {{ knp_menu_render('main') }} in twig.

My composer autoload:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

`symfony console debug:container app.menubuilder` gives me this:

```
Information for Service "app.menu_builder"
==========================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                                        
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       app.menu_builder
  Class            App\Menu\MenuBuilder
  Tags             knp_menu.menu_builder (method: createMainMenu, alias: main)
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes                                                          
  Autoconfigured   yes
  Usages           knp_menu.menu_provider.lazy
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------


 ! [NOTE] The "app.menu_builder" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled.
```

How do i get Symfony to recognize my classses?

Comment: Btw my composer autoload has:
`"App\\": "src/"`

Comment: In general it is better to update the question itself when you have additional information such as your autoload config.  Are you working in development mode?  Have you tried clearing the cache?  When exactly are you getting the `not found` message?  Does `bin/console debug:container app.menu_builder` show anything useful?

Comment: It also seems that your constructor is missing in `MenuBuilder.php`, but you're providing `@knp_menu.factory` to the constructor

Comment: @Cerad , i tried clearing cache. I am in development mode.  I am getting this message when calling `{{ knp_menu_render('main') }}` in twig. I have edited my question to fully show you the `debug:container` output. I dont find anything useful there unfortunatly.

Comment: @Brent Sorry, I shortened the code a bit to make it more readable and omitted the constructor.

Comment: What it shows it that your service is being defined and tagged.  I'm not familiar with knp but just as a guess try adding `public: true` to your service definition.

Comment: I fiddled around a bit, and created a new symfony **--webapp** (current project is made from skeleton and gradually added dependencies to minimize the project size). I recreated the problem there and everything works just fine.

I think there is internal problem in my symfony application that occured on the way of expanding my "skeleton" app. I am going to rewrite whole app in **--webapp**.

Should i post this as an answer to my quesiton since the problem is too hard to recreate? I could also put the faulty project on github for anyone interested.

Comment: @Kacper yep weird trying to merge code and expand right now and can't get symfony 6 to recognize my app/encode/jwtclass so closest thing to an answer so far